# ASP Classic Fire and Forget

Tags: jquery, sql, asynchronous, asp-classic, ado

I have a "Remote Control" webpage that lets me "manage" key stats for a website e.g there is a page that shows the stats, no of records, dates, times things happened, whether they have happened or not and so on.

Then I have "a remote control" page which lets me fire off certain tasks such as 
"run job A"
"set value of X to C"
"delete records in table B"

and so on.

This is just a list of links that then runs an SQL ADO Command with an ADO Connection string.

At the moment the page waits for the response of the stored procedure so it can show any error messages etc on the page.

However I want to add some jobs to the stored proc that could consume quite a while e.g 30-90 minutes long (jobs that should have run in the middle of the night etc) so if I am out and can see these jobs haven't tun I can fire a process to start them.

However I obviously don't want to lock my webpage up by waiting for the return code of the stored proc.

Ideally I would like to do something like fire an HTTP Non Blocking Get Request or in .NET an Aysnc Begin NonQuery like action. So I could fire the command on the DB and then return from that straight away.

However I don't know how I can do that in ASP Classic. Fire n Forget.

Maybe I have my Sunday head on or just need to think a bit more out the box e.g use jQyuery and AJAX to do a non blocking HTTP Request to another page THAT then fires the SQL query waits for it (Server.ScriptTimeout=0, CommandTimeout = 0) and then when it comes back with the response just do nothing with it.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting question, I've never tried it but could you not the use the `ExecuteOptionEnum` `adAsyncExecute` when calling `ADODB.Command` `Execute()` method?

Comment: Since you're stuck with classic asp, how about creating a SQL table with an insert trigger that would kick off your stored procs?  You would have a code for each command that you want to do, and all you would have to do would be to insert a row to that table, and the trigger will handle the rest.  

Doing this, you could even use this table as an audit log, putting datetime of when the command was executed, who executed it, etc.

Comment: Interesting idea Larry, I might look into that.